# Remove duplicates where 3 columns contain the same value and keep record with highest value

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, duplicates, multiple-columns

I want to remove duplicates where asciiname, countrycode and provinceid contain the same values.

How can I do this?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[cities_geonames](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [geonameid] [float] NULL,
    [asciiname] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [country code] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [provinceid] [int] NOT NULL,
            [population] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_cities_geonames] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2743447,'Abelhal','PT',463,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2657842,'Aberchalder','GB',201,30);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2522470,'Acebuchal','ES',353,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2522446,'Aceuchal','ES',356,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2657756,'Achallader','GB',201,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2959625,'Achthal','DE',314,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2959626,'Achthal','DE',314,10);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2959627,'Achthal','DE',314,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2959363,'Affalterthal','DE',314,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2657642,'Aghalee','GB',202,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (4179245,'Ahaluna','US',60,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2958936,'Aich halden','DE',315,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2958937,'Aich halden','DE',315,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (6714269,'Air Halim Rambung','ID',551,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2958612,'Albrechtsthal','DE',312,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2958542,'Alexandrinenthal','DE',314,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2657476,'Allhallows','GB',203,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2956763,'Alten-thal','DE',310,4000);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2957440,'Alten-thal','DE',310,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2957169,'Althaldensleben','DE',302,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (2956888,'Altrosenthal','DE',312,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (1651600,'Aluhaluh','ID',565,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (736891,'Amigdhala','GR',513,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (736889,'Amigdhalea','GR',513,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (736890,'Amigdhalea','GR',513,30);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (265176,'Amigdhalea','GR',511,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (265178,'Amigdhalea','GR',502,650);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (265179,'Amigdhalea','GR',502,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (265180,'Amigdhalea','GR',512,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (265181,'Amigdhalea','GR',509,560);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (265182,'Amigdhalea','GR',509,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (265183,'Amigdhalea','GR',509,0);
INSERT INTO cities_geonames_test (geonameid,asciiname,[country code],provinceid,[population]) VALUES (265184,'Amigdhalea','GR',504,0);
```

**UPDATE**

My apologies, it turns out that I need one more thing: keep the record where the column `population` has the highest value, how would I incorporate that into this statement? (I've updated table create statement and insert statements)

```
WITH CTE (asciiname, [country code],provinceid, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
  SELECT asciiname, [country code],provinceid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY asciiname,[country code],provinceid ORDER BY id) AS  DuplicateCount
  FROM cities_geonames
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
  WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
GO
```

Comment: May I suggest not using spaces in column names ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with x as
(
select row_number() over 
  (partition by asciiname, [country code], provinceid order by population desc) rn
from cities_geonames
)
delete from x where rn > 1
```

Comment: thanks @RaphaëlAlthaus. I had just taken the columns from the description

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it worked for me for similar situation:

```
WITH CTE (asciiname, [country code],provinceid, DuplicateCount)
AS
(
  SELECT asciiname, [country code],provinceid,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY asciiname,[country code],provinceid ORDER BY id) AS  DuplicateCount
  FROM cities_geonames
)
DELETE
FROM CTE
  WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
GO
```

Before deleting if you wish to see result-set that is to be deleted, you can use:

```
WITH CTE (asciiname, [country code],provinceid, DuplicateCount)
    AS
    (
      SELECT asciiname, [country code],provinceid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY asciiname,[country code],provinceid ORDER BY asciiname) AS  DuplicateCount
      FROM cities_geonames
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE
      WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
    GO
```

For **Updated question**, try below query(I am sure this is correct syntactically as I have no tool to check right now, Its a idea how you can find where population is max) if it works, replace `select *` with `delete`:

```
WITH CTE (asciiname, [country code],provinceid, Population, DuplicateCount)
    AS
    (
      SELECT OCG.asciiname, OCG.[country code],OCG.provinceid, OCG.population, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OCG.asciiname,OCG.[country code],OCG.provinceid ORDER BY OCG.id) AS  DuplicateCount
      FROM cities_geonames OCG 
    )
    SELECT *, MAX(population)
    FROM CTE
      WHERE DuplicateCount > 1
      GROUP BY Population,asciiname,provinceid,DuplicateCount,[country code]
         HAVING MAX(population) <>Population 
    GO
```

Comment: Thanks, also for the extra effort in showing what data will be deleted. Turns out I need my delete statement to incorporate the value in the `population` column...could you help?

Comment: You can add as many column in CTE as you need, right now there are three, this can be more also. Add `population` in both & select and CTE will contain duplicate dataset including `population` column.

Comment: It's not a duplciate, if multiple duplicates are found I want to keep the row that has the highest value for its `population` column.

Comment: @Flo,Updated answer for that, please check if it's working (I think it might have some minor syntactical error that can be rectified by you)

Comment: Thanks. I added 'population' column to your updated answer to fix a missing column error However, now I get `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` And I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: For that change `=` in where condition with `in`. It might be because subquery to get max population returns multiple rows. Using  `OCG.population in (...)` should work.

Comment: Thanks. With your final code I get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.` I already tried placing brackets around the reserved word `population`

Comment: Please try now, I am editing on mobile so wasn't to see simple mistake that group by must be before having. :)

Comment: Even more impressive :) I changed it (also added 'OCG' after FROM cities_geonames) and now I get `Column 'CTE.asciiname' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` But when I add all missing columns nothing is selected at all.

Comment: I tried what you've now done in your last update, adding all column names, but in that case, still no results are shown, so I suppose not duplicates are found, but I know there are.

Comment: Please check you should't have `population` in `Partition by` columns & you have duplicate data

Comment: I copied your exact last statement (which does not have `population` in `Partition by`) and I checked, the duplicate data is still there.

Comment: My mobile battery is saying bye to data connection, couldn't help :(